# Convert dict of scalars to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Under Python3, I have a dict with the following format:

```
my_dict = {'col1': 1.0, 'col2':2.0, 'col3': 3.0}
```

And I want to convert it to a pandas DataFrame using dict keys as columns:

```
      col1  col2  col3
0     1.0   2.0   3.0
```

However, when I try the following command I have a ValueError:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([my_dict])
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index').T
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict, index=[0])
```

---

```
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
0   1.0   2.0   3.0
```

Comment: which would you recommend and why? :)